# ipfw не справляется с большой нагрузкой

Tags: freebsd, firewall, ipfw

Настраиваю ipfw для локального почтового серерва. Все работает прекрасно, но спустя некоторое время (от полутора дней, до пары часов) наблюдается некорректная работа:
почта с других доменов приходит, но от моего почтовика на другой домен почта не уходит.Перегрузка или отключения ipfw сразу же решают проблему. При чем почта внутри моего домена работает на ура.
Почтовик у меня - postfix, dovecot, MySQl
Вот мои правила:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd="/sbin/ipfw -q"
${cmd} -f flush
#loopback
${cmd} add 10 allow ip from any to any via lo0
${cmd} add 11 deny ip from any to 127.0.0.1/8
${cmd} add 12 deny ip from 127.0.0.1/8 to any 
#
${cmd} add 20 allow tcp from any to any established

#table ssh 22
table_ssh=22
${cmd} table $table_ssh flush
${cmd} table $table_ssh add 192.168.0.48

#icmp
${cmd} add 30 allow icmp from 192.168.0.0/24 to me
${cmd} add 30 allow icmp from me to 192.168.0.0/24 

#ssh
${cmd} add 40 allow tcp from "table(22)" to me 22 in via em0 
${cmd} add 41 deny log tcp from any to me 22 in via em0
#mail, web
${cmd} add 50 deny tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to me 25,110,143,80 in via em0
${cmd} add 51 allow tcp from any to me 25,110,143,80 in via em0

#servers rules
${cmd} add 60 allow ip from me to any out via em0
#UDP Server
${cmd} add 61 allow udp from me to any dst-port 53 out via em0
${cmd} add 62 allow udp from any to me src-port 53 in via em0

echo "I do it."
```

Comment: _но от моего почтовика на другой домен почта не уходит_, не уходит с какой ошибкой? в `/var/log/security` отображается, что именно ipfw отбросил IP, куда не уходит?

Comment: попробуйте `add 60 allow ip from me to any setup`

Comment: Вот только добавил правило которое логирует все откинутые пакеты.

Comment: что даст это правило? add 60 allow ip from me to any setup????